# Readstream path

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark, pyspark, streaming

I have say a/b/c/date/Xyz.txt how can I pick up the path dynamically, date is changing randomly. Other directory fields remains the same like a/b/c/dateIsChanging/Xyz.txt

Someone is adding file random date directory, how can I get the path, each time when it is added

a/b/c/dateIsChanging/Xyz.txt  here in directory under random chosen by the user, I want to pick it up whatever date comes in
Date in YYYYMMDD formate

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what one would do:

```py
import os
import datetime as dt

# create a date for folder name
date_part = dt.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# generate the folder path
the_path = os.path.join('C:\\','test',str(date_part),'file_name.txt')

print(the_path)
```

the output:

```
C:\test\2022-03-24\file_name.txt
```

Obviously, would need to adjust for your particular operating system and date format.

Comment: Here we are adding time based on current time, date is random chosen by the user, I want to read whatever date comes in